# Multiclass Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, machine-learning, python

This question is based on the Multiclass Linear Discriminant Analysis (MLDA) describe in [Lectures slides by Olga Veksler](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/%7Eoveksler/Courses/CS434a_541a/Lecture8.pdf), which is a generalization of Fisher's Linear Discriminant. My use in MLDA is to reduce dimensionality and transform multi-dimensional data into "well separated" clusters in lower dimensions.

**Short review of the theory and mathematical formalism:**

Suppose we have $N$ samples in $C$ classes or clusters. Each have $N_c$ samples which are $d$-dimensional, that is $x^{(c)}_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for $c = 1,...,C$ and $i = 1,...,N_c$. Each class $\omega_c$ have mean and covariance:
$$
\mu_c = \frac{1}{N_c} \sum_{x_i \in \omega_c} x_i, \qquad S_c = \frac{1}{N_c}\sum_{x_i \in \omega_c} (x_i - \mu_c) (x_i - \mu_c)^T
$$
The "average" scatter within classes is defined as
$$
S_w = \sum_{c=1}^C S_c \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}
$$
and the scatter between classes is defines as
$$
S_b = \sum_{c=1}^{C} N_c (\mu_c - \mu)(\mu_c - \mu)^T \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}
$$
where $\mu = (1/N)\sum_{j=1}^n x_j$ is the mean over all the samples.
In order to find the best separating dimensionality reduction, given by projection $y = W^T x$, we want to maximize the following objective function:
$$
J(W) = \frac{\det(W^T S_b W)}{\det(W^T S_w W)}
$$
The idea is to maximize the scatter between while minimizing the scatter within each class. Differentiating the objective function with respect to $W$ one gets the following generalized eigenvalue problem:
$$
S_b W_c = J(W_c) S_w W_c = \lambda S_w W_c
$$
where $J(W_c) \in \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar eigenvalue. From matrix rank consideration one can show that there are at most $C-1$ non-zero eigenvectors. The projection weights are the $C-1$ eigenvectors corresponding to the $C-1$ largest eigenvalues. We stack the eigenvectors in a matrix and get the weight matrix
$$
W = \left[ W_1 | ... | W_{C-1} \right] \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times (C-1)}
$$
Then the projection is $y = W^T x$ (verify dimensions: $(C-1) \times 1 = ((C-1) \times d) \cdot (d \times 1)$).

This projection is called LDA or MDA.

The new means after LDA are given by $\tilde{\mu}_c = W^T \mu_c$ and the covariances after LDA are given by
$$
\tilde{S}_c = W^T S_c W \in \mathbb{R}^{(C-1) \times (C-1)}
$$

**Here I have few questions:**

1. Is the after-LDA covariance matrix of each class, $\tilde{S}_c$ is diagonal? The $W^T S_c W$ is sort of a whitening transformation and if $W^T = W^{-1}$ it is diagonalization.
2. How to solve the generalized eigenvalues problem $S_b v = \lambda S_w v$? If I tried different algorithms in Python such as SciPy's `eig` or `eigh` functions with `D, V = eig(S_b, S_w)`, or inverting $S_w$ and then solve $S_r v = S_w^{-1} S_b v = \lambda v$ and `D, V = eigh(S_r)`, or trying SVD: `V, D, Vh = svd(S_r)` I get different eigenvalues and eigenvactors.
3. How to use SVD to solve the generalized eigenvalues problem?
4. If I use `sklearn` LDA class I also get different results, but the algorithm therein is more complicated and include shrinkage covariance estimator, and priors terms.

The best results were obtained with

```
from scipy.linalg import pinv, eig, eigh

# Solving for eigenvectors by inverting cov_within
inv_cov_within = pinv(cov_within)
D, V = eigh(inv_cov_within @ cov_between)
    
# Sort according to eigenvalues in descending order
idx = np.argsort(np.real(D))[::-1]
D = D[idx]
W = V[:, idx]

# The weights are (n_features, n_classes-1)
weights = W[:, 0:n_classes-1]
```

I used `pinv` because the scatter within may not be invertible (e.g. when $d >> N$, more dimensions than samples), so I use pseudo-inverse. Using SVD may also solve this issue (how?).

Hypothesis for 1:
The class covariances are diagonal only if $\forall c : S_c = S$, i.e. all the classes have the same covariance matrix.

**References:**

- [Lectures slides by Olga Veksker](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/%7Eoveksler/Courses/CS434a_541a/Lecture8.pdf)
- [https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/08/a-brief-introduction-to-linear-discriminant-analysis/)
- [Intelligent Data Analysis and Probabilistic Inference Lecture 15](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Edfg/ProbabilisticInference/old_IDAPILecture15.pdf)
- [Optimal $\mathbf{W}$'s columns are the generalized eigenvectors in $\mathbf{S}_\text{B}\mathbf{v}_i = \lambda_i \mathbf{S}_\text{W} \mathbf{v}_i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052642/optimal-mathbfws-columns-are-the-generalized-eigenvectors-in-mathbfs)