# Reason behind objective function in Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, machine-learning

I don't really understand the objective function to be optimized in Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA). My question is centered around the same concepts mentioned in this [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4508932/multiclass-linear-discriminant-analysis) other one.

The analysis focuses on two concepts also used in ANOVA (Analysis of Variance):

- the within-class scatter $s_w$
- the between-class scatter $s_b$
- the total scatter $s$

These quantities are real numbers but it is quite common to define three $d \times d $ matrices $S_w$, $S_b$, and $S$ such that for any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ the numbers  $x^TS_wx$, $x^TS_bx$, and $x^TSx$ correspond, respectively, to the within-class scatter, the between-class scatter, and the total scatter of the original data projected onto the one-dimensional subspace generated by $x$.

Each matrix represents a bilinear form w.r.t. the canonical basis. If $W$ is an orthonormal  matrix, then $W^TS_bW$ represents the same bilinear form as $S_b$ but with respect to a rotated orthonormal basis and similarly for $S_w$ and $S$.

The objective of LDA is maximise the function

$$J(W) = \frac{det(W^TS_bW)}{det(W^TS_wW)}$$

What I don't understand is that $det(W^TS_bW)$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $W^TS_bW$ but the scatter in the rotated basis is instead the sum of the eigenvalues and similarly for $S_b$. Moreover $det(W^TS_wW)$ may be $0$.

References:

- [Lectures slides](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/%7Eoveksler/Courses/CS434a_541a/Lecture8.pdf) by O. Veksler
- [Expository paper](https://www.dss.uniroma1.it/it/system/files/pubblicazioni/Fordellone.pdf) by M. Fordellone et. al